# Selenium python find by name but name = "name"

Tags: python, selenium

I using selenium i try sed_keys() but element on website have only name and this name is "name".

```
driver.find_element_by_name("name")
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
```

Edit:And the items on the page named = "name are two and I want to add a text to the second

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message and stack trace.

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: You need to find something unique in the parents of the INPUT that you want. If you want our help with that, you'll have to include more HTML from around both the INPUTs. The URL would be extra helpful.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I don't think he's getting an error. It sounds like there are two elements that match his current locator and the `send_keys()` is going to the wrong (first) element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would find something unique in the DOM above the element you want and use that to build a locator that finds only the element you want. One quick fix would be to use `find_elements()` (note the plural) and get the second element.

```
driver.find_elements_by_name("name")[1].send_keys("some text")
                   ^ the 's' will return a collection
                                     ^ use array notation to pick the one you want
```

The problem is if this page changes, e.g. the element order is changed, another matching element is added, etc., then this will start sending text to the wrong element again.

Answer (score -1):

the method which you have given should work , jut try using xpath

```
your_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="name"]').click()
```

Comment: This added but to the first one